# My Dropdown menu in Tailwind CSS takes on the whole area of the navbar background on hovering

Tags: tailwind-css

I created this dropdown menu in Tailwind CSS but it takes on the whole area of the navbar background instead of being above or atleast outside of it on hover. I'm new to tailwind and have tried going through documentation in such of helpful utility classes but all to no avail.
This is my code snippet below[This is before Hover[This is after Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKveC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj85E.png)

```
<!-- Menu NavBar-->
    <nav class="bg-lightDustyRose p-4">
        <div class="container mx-auto">
            <div class="hidden space-x-9 md:flex">
                <div>
                    <button class="peer text-white hover:text-gray-500">Home</button>
                    <div class="hidden peer-hover:flex hover:flex w-[200px] flex-col bg-white drop-shadow-lg ">
                        <a class="px-5 py-3 hover:bg-gray-200" href="#">About Us</a>
                        <a class="px-5 py-3 hover:bg-gray-200" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                        <a class="px-5 py-3 hover:bg-gray-200" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>  
     </nav>
```

I tried adding a z index but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding position classes. The container of the links menu needs the `absolute` class, and the container of that, needs the `relative` class so it doesn't completely escapes the page structure. You can read more about the `position` css property **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)** and how to use the position classes in tailwind **[here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/position)**

```
<nav class="bg-lightDustyRose p-4">
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="hidden space-x-9 md:flex">
      <div class="relative"> <--here--<<
        <button class="peer text-white hover:text-gray-500">Home</button>
        <div class="absolute hidden peer-hover:flex hover:flex w-[200px] flex-col bg-white drop-shadow-lg "> <--here--<<
          <a class="px-5 py-3 hover:bg-gray-200" href="#">About Us</a>
          <a class="px-5 py-3 hover:bg-gray-200" href="#">Contact Us</a>
          <a class="px-5 py-3 hover:bg-gray-200" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</nav>
```